# Meaning of the string representation of an StdGen type in Haskell

Tags: haskell, random

I would like to clarify my understanding of how the `System.Random` of Haskell works after reading the I/O chapter of Learn You a Haskell For A Great Good.

From what I understand, a value of type `StdGen` behaves like the generating seed of a random-sequence. That would mean the `StdGen` type is nothing but a kind of tagged (but random) integer, with the tag being `StdGen`. Is this correct?

Also `getStdGen` queries the operating system (or something else possibly?) for a starting seed and the result of executing that action gets stored in `gen`.

Whenever I try to print a value of type `StdGen` I see two largish integers always separated by a white-space, as you can see below. I would have imagined that this value would have been a *single* integer. So what does that white-space stand for?

```
Prelude System.Random> gen <- getStdGen
Prelude System.Random> 
Prelude System.Random> gen
751404879 1655838864
Prelude System.Random>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`StdGen` is just a pseudo-random number generator which uses two seed values.

The authors of `StdGen` have decided to implement its Show instance as just showing the two seed values separated by a space instead of using a more conventional format.

The exact algorithm is given by `stdNext` in [`System.Random`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/random-1.1/docs/src/System-Random.html#stdNext).

Answer (score 6):

> From what I understand, a value of type `StdGen` behaves like the generating seed of a random-sequence.

This is correct.

> That would mean the `StdGen` type is nothing but a kind of tagged (but random) integer, with the tag being `StdGen`.

This does not follow. There is no a priori reason to believe that the internal state of a PRNG is a completely unstructured number. Different algorithms use different internal data structures. In the case of `StdGen`, you can [read the source](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/random-1.1/docs/src/System-Random.html#StdGen):

```
data StdGen 
 = StdGen !Int32 !Int32
```

For this particular algorithm, the internal state is two 32-bit numbers. Other algorithms use [more complicated data structures](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mwc-random-0.13.4.0/docs/src/System-Random-MWC.html#line-313).

> Also getStdGen queries the operating system (or something else possibly?) for a starting seed

There is a global `IORef` containing the seed that notionally gets initialized to `mkStdRNG 0` at program startup; you can see the details [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/random-1.1/docs/src/System-Random.html#getStdGen).

> Whenever I try to print a value of type StdGen I see two largish integers always separated by a white-space, as you can see below. So what does that white-space stand for?

It separates the two `Int32` values contained in a `StdGen`.